# sklearn syntax error despite existing working code

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn

I have the following code in Python 2.7 whose goal is to create a plot of the results of an SVM using numpy, pylab, and sklearn:

```
import numpy, pylab
from sklearn.svm import SVC

DataTable = numpy.genfromtxt('path/data.csv',delimiter=',',dtype=None)[1:]

DataPoints,TruthValues = (DataTable[:,[1,2] ]).astype(numpy,float), (DataTable[:,0]=='1')

TrainedSVC = SVC(C = 100, kernel = 'linear').fit(DataPoints,TruthValues)

x_max,y_max,x_min,y_min = DataPoints[:, 0].max(),DataPoints[:, 1].max(),DataPoints[:, 0].min(),DataPoints[:, 1].min()

xx, yy = numpy.meshgrid(numpy.arange(x_min, x_max, (int(x_max)-int(x_min)/200.0), numpy.arange(y_min, y_max, (int(y_max)-int(y_min)/200.0))

GridEvaluation = TrainedSVC.predict(numpy.c_[xx.ravel(),yy.ravel()]).reshape(xx.shape)

pylab.pcolormesh(xx, yy, GridEvaluation, alpha=0.1)
pylab.scatter(DataPoints[:, 0], DataPoints[:, 1], c=TruthValues)
pylab.xlabel('crp');pylab.ylabel('income');pylab.show()
```

The code was originally posted on [this blog](https://dbaumgartel.wordpress.com/2014/03/10/a-scikit-learn-example-in-10-lines/), which does a good job explaining each part of the code.  I left everything essentially the same as in the sample code, but I still get a syntax error on the line `GridEvaluation = TrainedSVC.predict(numpy.c_[xx.ravel(),yy.ravel()]).reshape(xx.shape)`

What confuses me is that this error didn't come up in the above blog post despite the fact that the line it occurs on is copied verbatim from the post.  If it helps I'm using the Anaconda distribution of Python with Spyder IDE.

UPDATE: Upon taking into account the answer below I now get the response:

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`

on the line:

`xx, yy = numpy.meshgrid(numpy.arange(int(x_min), int(x_max), (int(x_max)-int(x_min)/200.0)), numpy.arange(y_min, y_max, (int(y_max)-int(y_min)/200.0)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've missed some parentheses when casting to int in the line above.

```
xx, yy = numpy.meshgrid(numpy.arange(x_min, x_max, (int(x_max)-int(x_min)/200.0)), numpy.arange(y_min, y_max, (int(y_max)-int(y_min)/200.0)))
```

Comment: Unfortunately when making that change I receive the error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: What's your input data? Is the TypeError on the corrected line of code? If so, it seems you are reading in strings not numeric values. Maybe check your input file

Comment: Yep, that's on the corrected line of code.  You might be right about the input file, let me check to be sure.  UPDATE: All values are numeric except headers.